# The issue was/is that the staffs were corrupt

Tags: verbs, past-tense, present-tense

In this example, is `was` the correct verb?

> Few years ago, a company went bankrupt. The issue was/is that the staffs were corrupt.

If I understand correctly, the issue remains the issue today and in the future, so "is" can also be used. However, I am not sure if it should actually be "was" because the event happened in the past.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context of the two sentences suggests that the issue *was* the reason for bankruptcy at the time:

> Few years ago, a company went bankrupt. The issue was that the staff
>   were corrupt.

(the collective noun *staff* doesn't take 's' for plural')

To make it clear that the issue exists now, it is better to use additional words:

> Few years ago, a company went bankrupt. The issue still remains, that
>   the staff were corrupt (then).

Comment: Thank you @Alex_ander. Does it mean that using `is` in `Few years ago, a company went bankrupt. The issue is that the staff were corrupt.` is wrong?

Comment: It is not wrong grammatically (with the combination of tenses used), but it sounds unclear (up to looking wrong) without additional specific context, which I suggested for axample. That is because _natural_ logic of events puts 'issue' (as the reason for bancruptsy) to the _past_. If you leave that text 'as is', a question about the **issue** will arise: so it's not about the reason for bankruptcy, then is it about _current_ problems e. g. with reputation of some related company? Some explanation is expected after such a sentence.